# Repository not found: while pushing to remote branch

Tags: git, github, version-control, repository

I was trying to push my code to remote repository.While pushing, it throws repo not found error.Previously I have pushed my code to remote repository

I tried removing and adding remote repository using

git remote rm origin

git remote add origin https://github.com/xx/yy.git

and also tried below command to add remote repository

git remote add origin https://username:password@github.com/username/repo-name.git

after adding remote repo, able to see the remote has been added ,but while pushing it throws not found error

git push --set-upstream origin master  https://username:password@github.com/username/repo-name.git

Tried above command to push, but same error has been thrown.

***EDIT***
Error:

remote: Repository not found.

fatal: repository 'https://github.com/username/repo-name.git/' not found

***EDIT***

Anyone please help me to resolve this error

Comment: What's the entire error?

Comment: Also, just for completeness' sake, are you sure you have the correct URL?

Comment: @JimRedmond I have correct url. added the error message in question